# Black Friday Discounts

Tags: cheap, deals, gear

As long as it's got an online store, we might all be able to buy, so if you've found a good deal, please share!

http://www.sweetwater.com/dealzone/computer-audio-deals
the bulk of the better deals are for demo stock. The M-Audio Oxygen 49 is going for $99 (RRP $199)
http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Oxygen2-49

http://www.sound-ideas.com/order.html
Sound Ideas are having a 50% sale of all products

Amazon is having pretty decent deals, but nothing that I thought was overly smashing. Anyways, the idea is to share, so if you find something good please post it here. Let's target for discounts that are 50% or more and hopefully we might all be able to get ourselves some early Christmas presents.

Comment: Waves are doing discounts up to 70%
http://waves.com/#1
opens 12 midnight PST

Comment: I saw a Blue Icicle for 25 bucks somewhere... I'll try to find it..

Answer (score 2):

We are having a black friday sale through sunday at [Rabbit Ears Audio](http://rabbitearsaudio.com).  We are doing 20% off all single-user licenses with this discount code: rabbitfriday

The sale will start today and run through Sunday (-500 GMT)

Thanks,

Michael Raphael
[Rabbit Ears Audio](http://rabbitearsaudio.com)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you (there are links to many black friday offers, but german): http://mixingroom.de/musiksoftware-musikprogramme-aller-art-um-bis-zu-70-prozent-reduziert/

Comment: awesome! here's the translated site
http://translate.google.com.au/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://mixingroom.de/musiksoftware-musikprogramme-aller-art-um-bis-zu-70-prozent-reduziert/&ei=sdXOToqsKaytiQeJn4DRDg&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCMQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://mixingroom.de/musiksoftware-musikprogramme-aller-art-um-bis-zu-70-prozent-reduziert/%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DSGP%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26prmd%3Dimvns